# How to delete unused artifacts and rebuild index in sonatype nexus3 using java?

Tags: java, indexing, sonatype, nexus3, rebuild

When I am deleting the artifacts from Nexus3 repository, few of the manifest file is still pending in the repository. These are not being deleted completely from the nexus3. However few suggestions that I got is to "rebuild index".

How to rebuild the index so that it will allow me to show all the specified artifacts deleted?

I have tried using this library to delete the artifacts from nexus `repos.com.github.dockerjava.api.command.RemoveImageCmd`.
However artifacts are being deleted from this library, but few of them are remaining like manifest files.

```
RemoveImageCmd removeImageCmd = client.removeImageCmd(imageFullName).withForce(true);
            removeImageCmd.exec();
```

I expect to have output as deleted all the artifacts from the nexus repo along with the manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to delete other files like json,txt,zip file from nexus repo, however i am not able to delete giving below error logs :

2019-09-18T23:16:21.880Z        http-nio-8083-exec-9    ERROR   org.acumos.portal.be.controller.MarketPlaceCatalogServiceController             User=Xmen, X-ACUMOS-Request-Id=51ed823b-474a-4449-b6e4-1c4c3fc40a1e, ClientIPAddress=XYZ.24.0.4, ServerFQDN=acumos-portal-be AcumosServiceException Occurred while deleteSolutionArtifacts() org.acumos.portal.be.common.exception.AcumosServiceException: 404 nexusRepoURL:8081/repository/acumos-dev-docker/v2/vt_delete_2_webcrosssellanalytics_adae47d5-7249-4bdf-b1f8-fe4a6343e36b/manifests/1

my nexus repository's path for manifest file is : 
http://nexusRepoURL:8081/repository/acumos-dev-docker/v2/vt_delete_2_webcrosssellanalytics_adae47d5-7249-4bdf-b1f8-fe4a6343e36b/manifests/1

Comment: Use Nexus Client to delete the artifacts from Nexus repository first, then try to delete the related records in database.